# File not found in Setup section on InnoSetup script

Tags: inno-setup

I have an InnoSetup script I have been using for years, and suddenly it stopped working, specifically on this line in the [Setup] section:

```
WizardImageFile={src}\..\..\images\InstallBanner.bmp
```

The error reported is:

```
Compiler Error!
Line 47: Could not read "C:\projects\xxxx\installer\{src}\..\..\images\installbanner.bmp".
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Two potential problems I noticed, `{src}` is still in the file path reported, and the file name is all lowercase. Except for these two issues, the file name is correct, and the file exists.

Am I using the `{src}` constant incorrectly and this has previously worked by coincidence, or is this a bug that was introduced with an update?

Currently running 6.0.2. I know 6.0.4 is released, but cannot currently install it, and didn't notice an issue like this mentioned in the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) in [`WizardImageFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardimagefile). It makes no sense. The constants are evaluated on runtime. While `WizardImageFile` is read on compile time. Also `{src}` refers to the path, from where an installation was started. How would it evaluate, when you are only building the installer?

If it ever worked, you must have subfolder with literal name `{src}` somewhere on the path, where you were compiling the installer.

Comment: Then what is the origin or base path used in `WizardImageFile`? Also, I have never had a folder with the name `{src}`

Comment: Probably the folder of your `.iss` file. In your case it is `C:\projects\xxxx\installer`, as you can see from the error message.

Comment: I thought of that, but if I remove `{src}`, `C:\projects\xxxx\installer` is no longer part of the path either. I assume it just uses the current working directory in that case

Comment: For me, `WizardImageFile` is resolved relatively to the `iss` file. Anyway, that's a different topic. If you wanted to ask how to resolve `WizardImageFile` relatively to `iss` file, then you have asked a wrong question. I have answered what you have asked :)

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinPrikryl said, `{src}` and other constants cannot be used as they are evaluated at runtime. Definitions may be used, and the `{#SourcePath}` definition works as a starting path relative to the script location

```
WizardImageFile={#SourcePath}\..\..\images\InstallBanner.bmp
```

Comment: If you want this to be a valid answer, you should change your question to ask *"how to resolve `WizardImageFile` relatively to `iss` file"*.

Comment: When I created the question, I didn't realize that is what I needed, since what I had worked for some reason in previous versions